# Disable "overwrite" confirmation for folders in Notepad++

Tags: windows-10, notepad++

Whenever I write a new file in Notepad++ and want to save it in certain folder, I usually:

- copy this folder's path to clipboard from some source (Total Commander, file explorer etc.),
- paste it to "Save as" dialog in Notepad++,
- hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm.

Since one of recent updates to Notepad++ program started to warn me that given folder exists and asking me whether I want to replace it:

[image]

This is pointless (Notepad++ is **not** overwriting a folder!), stupid and annoying. Notepad++ is the only software that I use that shows this kind of confirmation window after manually changing folder.

Is there any way to disable this behaviour and block Notepad++ from showing this kind of confirmation windows?

**Edit**: *The problem exists only if you don't have path delimiter at the end of pasted path, i.e. for `c:\Trash\Delphi 7` above message box will be displayed and for `c:\Trash\Delphi 7\` it won't be*.

Comment: It seems that you misunderstood the question. The confirmation screen in question appears after I paste _path_ only and hit Enter. There is no filename part yet, so Notepad++ should not display anything AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this comment](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/4926#issuecomment-430357942) at Notepad++'s GitHub issues tracker the described behaviour seems to be some kind of bug only when "old" style of dialogs is enabled (which seems to be default for new installations of N++).

Making sure that *Settings > Preferences > Default Directory > Use new style save dialog (without file extension feature & Unix style path capacity)* option is **enabled** solves the problem.

However, there's a price to be paid (as always). When "new" dialog styles are enabled, [Notepad++ defaults "Save" and "Save as" dialogs to `*.*` (All types) instead of `*.txt`](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/3341) and thus forces user to change that every time a new file is being saved or manually type `*.txt` in file name (or it will be saved in file with no extension). Which can be even more annoying than a problem described in question.